# If statement syntax error

Tags: python, file, syntax-error

I have this snippet of code which is supposed to write files:

```python
with open('key.txt', 'w+') as key:
       counter += 1
       key.write(k + str(counter)
       contents = key.read()
       if contents == 'ran 1':
           print('Can\'t run twice!')
       else:
           writeFiles()
```

My Python compiler keeps complaining and throwing out this error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/fun.py", line 30                                                                                                                                                                                        
    if key.read() == 'ran: 1':                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                             ^                                                                                                                                                                                                         
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I really don't understand what this means, I usually don't get an error like this. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: your error doesn't match your code posted....

Comment: As @RNar hinted: Please check again what you reported as error, as this would be a quite different python language your "Python copliler" adheres to. I would guess, that in real life the token `contents` made the parser bail out because the expression `k + str(counter) contents` is invalid python. Rationale: If people come here seeking for solutions, they are better served, when they find consistent questions with accepted working solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

missing closing parenthesis:

```
key.write(k + str(counter)
                          ^ here
```

should be

```
key.write(k + str(counter))
```

Whenever you see these kind of *mystery* syntax errors, look on the previous lines

Comment: I especially like the hint (and if the OP checks again the reported error ... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You have a missing parantheses in your `key.write` line

```
with open('key.txt', 'w+') as key:
   counter += 1
   key.write(k + str(counter))
   contents = key.read()
   if contents == 'ran 1':
       print('Can\'t run twice!')
   else:
       writeFiles()
```

Comment: this is pretty much the same as my answer

Comment: Yeah.. I'm pretty slow at typing. Didn't notice your answer